# Controlling a directive from another directive the angular way

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

Say I have one directive making fixtures and then another one giving me that fixture data on another part of the screen (call it 'match' directive).

What is the best way to do this so that I have access to the fixture controller's functions in the **match** directive?

Comment: you could have nested directive, `fixtures` directive would be the parent and then the its child are `fixture`, & they would have `require: '^fixtures'` options which will give access to the fixture controller variable and methods.. Basically the fixture directive controller will have a methods/data which can be sharable among all child directive..they can have 4th parameter inside the link function which will give controller object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always share data using shared services injected in both controllers of both directives.

Answer (score 1):

Directives talk to each other via controllers, also you can use broadcast and on events of Anguler js to achieve the same.